# Does not work Angular validation with @ViewChildren parent and multiple child

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Does not work Angular validation with @ViewChildren parent and  multiple child.

In the parent used multiple child componets

```
 @ViewChildren('aaa') pList:QueryList<PComponent>;
```

Able to get child component values.

But cannot validate. Save button in the parent form. If we check child field values as valid then return false does not apply.

```
      let index1 = 0 ;
  @ViewChildren('pDirection') pList:QueryList<PComponent>;
  pFormArray.controls.forEach(ele => {
      let pList = this.pList.toArray()[index1];
      let stationList = pList ["portRotationForm"]["controls"]["stationFormArray"]["controls"];

      stationList.forEach(elements => {

        if (elements.controls["countryName"].invalid ) {
        validForm = false;
        }


      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't able to understand your question, if you want to validate the child component form in parent component. Here is the apprach.

**ParentComponent:**

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <childComponent [formGroup]="formGroup"></<childComponent>
  <childComponent [formGroup]="formGroup"></<childComponent>
  <childComponent [formGroup]="formGroup"></<childComponent>
</form>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childComponent: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
this.childComponent[0].ValidateForm();
this.childComponent[1].ValidateForm();
```

Note: i considered 'ChildComponent' as the class name for your child component.

**Child Component:**

```
ValidateForm(){
  //Form Field Validation should happen here
  //return only the status
}
```

Comment: Yes.  added the code top. Have multiple child ?? @ViewChildren